# WPF Window.Loaded and Window.Closed

Tags: wpf, events, triggers

There are two event triggers. One of them is `RoundedEvent` `Window.Loaded` and the the other `Window.Closed`.
But both of them does not work at the same time. How can I fix The problem?

My code is below

```
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Closed">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation  Storyboard.TargetName="mainWindow" 
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Left"
        From="500" To="-200" Duration="0:0:1" >
                </DoubleAnimation>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>

    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation
        Storyboard.TargetName="mainWindow" 
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Left"
        From="-200" To="500" Duration="0:0:1" />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Window.Loaded` works fine, the problem is that `EventTriggers` only work for routed events but `Window.Closed` is not routed event (since it is something that can only occur to a window).

I suggest you do the closing animation in code-behind by handling the `Window.Closed` event, it makes sense anyway because you need to wait for the animation to end before you actually close the window.